# Cross Site Scripting threat

Tags: php, html

I have a piece of code giving risk of XSS.

```
<select size="1" name='department'>
    <option value='<?php echo $department?>' selected><?php echo $department?></option>
    <option value="Dept1">Dept1</option>
    <option value="Dept2">Dept2</option>
```

When I tried to replace the line with

```
<option value='<?php echo htmlspecialchars($department, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')?>' selected><?php echo htmlspecialchars($department, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')?></option>
```

It is still identifying it as Cross Site scripting threat. Is there anything I could be missing

Comment: *What* is identifying it as a threat? Also, yes, there is a threat there. And please preview your code before posting (there's a preview right below the box where you typed your question, above the button you clicked to submit it); your question was originally unintelligible due to the lack of formatting.

Comment: Thanks for correcting. There is a tool which notifies us of any threat in code. The second line of the piece of code was asked to be updated to remove XSS threat. Using htmlspecialchars did not resolve it

Comment: Is the threat related only to this 'select'  or the whole form itself?

Comment: Is `$department` comming from the client (get, post...) ? `echo strip_tags($department);` should suffice.

Comment: which tool did you use? I only see a select form, which can't be the problem on itself. 2 Options left: the generated PHP value or the way you submit yor form (with javascript??)

Comment: $department is coming from the user input. This is part of a html page where error is shown.

Answer (score 0):

Snippet code performs output encoding and prevents it from Cross-Site Scripting. It will convert the payload such as:

```
'"><test>
```

to

```
&#039;&quot;&gt;&lt;test&gt;
```

It might be possible that there could be other reason in context with some other page or full code and that could be the reason why tool reported it.